# Custom Component in Tab Pane not Interactive

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, custom-component

I created a custom component, PlayerEditableRow, and I placed it in a anchor pane, PlayersTable, which is in a tab, PlayersTab, but my editable row components are not interactive. For example, I have a a button and combobox that do not respond when I click on them. The PlayersTable also doesn't respond to mouse click listeners, either. The custom components do work, however, when I place the editable row in the PlayersTab anchor pane. This is the setup of my GUI:

The tab controller:

```
public class PlayersTab extends Tab implements IObserver {

@FXML private AnchorPane content;
@FXML private PlayersTable playerTable;

private void initView() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("players_tab.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(content);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setText("Players");
    this.setContent(content);

    playerTable.initializeController(gameSettings);
}
```

The fxml file:

```
<?import dominion.application.controller.PlayersTable?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" fx:id="content" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <VBox fx:id="playersVBox" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" spacing="10.0" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES">
          <children>
            <Label text="Players" >
              <font>
                <Font size="18.0" />
              </font>
              <VBox.margin>
                <Insets />
              </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <PlayersTable fx:id="playerTable" />
          </children>
        </VBox>
      </children>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
      </padding>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

The custom component:

```
public class PlayersTable extends AnchorPane implements IObserver {

@FXML private VBox playerTable;

private void initView() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("players_table.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    playerTable.getChildren().add(new PlayerEditableRow(PlayerType.COMPUTER, gameSettings));
}
```

The fxml file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" id="AnchorPane" blendMode="DARKEN" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <VBox fx:id="playerTable" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

What do I need to do to make my custom components interactive? I haven't had a problem with this before where I am using custom tab panes and custom anchor panes nested within each other.

Here is the image of my inactive component:

[image]

Comment: I am having same problem. Did you find solution?

Comment: No, and until i find a fix I just removed the extra anchor pane and put everything in the tab view.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post that as a comment, but Stackoverflow says I have to few reputations to do that ;) So I create an answer, maybe it can help...

Why don't you add your Playertables children and the Playerstab content and text in fxml? I mean it probably wouldn't solve the problem but would imho be nicer. I do that with my custom components which extend javafx core components.
And why don't you make use of `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader#setControllerFactory`? It should make your code cleaner and less coupled.